# Maintain scope when loading script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

Say I have a file 'test.js' with the following contents:

```
var test = 'something';
```

Then I have a primary script that needs to load up test.js to grab the test variable.

Obviously this works:

```
$.ajax({dataType: "script", cache: true, url: 'test.js'});
```

The issue is that the variable `test` exists in the global scope. I'm curious if there's a way to add it into an object and keep it out of the global scope.

Something like:

```
function scriptloader() {
    this.grabscript = function() {
        return $.ajax({dataType: "script", cache: true, url: 'test.js'});
    }
}

var myloader = new scriptloader();

myloader.grabscript();
```

Where ideally myloader would contain the loaded variable `test`. However, I can console.log(test) and still see 'something'.

Is there a way to lock the loaded script into scope or am I dreaming?

Comment: Interesting question... the only way I could think of isolating the loaded file in it's own context would be to load the file via an iframe, then extract the object from the parent

Comment: That's actually an interesting idea...

Comment: Couldn't one argue that if such a scenario is occuring then perhaps you should rethink your design approach as far as the placement of `var test = 'something';` is concerned??? Seems like there is a better place for it than in your `test.js` script since it is needed elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have control over test.js?

Comment: That's obviously a simple example. In reality it's loading in a script that acts as a model for a data set so my problem is I can't restructure it (i.e. contain it in an object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function scriptloader() {
  this.grabscript = function() {
    var loader = this;
    $.ajax('test.js', {
      complete: function(response) {
        var js = '(function() {' + response.responseText + ' loader.test = test; })();'
        eval(js);
      },
      dataType: 'text'
    });
  }
}
```

The `scriptloader` instance would then get a property called `test`.

Comment: Except that as soon as you run $.ajax the script get loaded and the contents enter the global scope

Comment: You mean because $.ajax is guessing that the response is JS, and automatically evaluating it? Yes, that's a good catch. I edited my response to include the 'type' option. This should prevent jQuery from evaluating the JS. As for where I call eval explicitly, it's wrapped in a closure, so no globals should be set.

Comment: also response.data should be `response.responseText`. You can forgo the var js = ... and just eval the responseText

Comment: Of course this only works when there are no cross origin restrictions :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval` for that purpose and create a variable with the expected name in the local scope:

```
(function(jsString) {
    var test;
    eval(jsString);
    console.log(test); // 'something'
})("var test = 'something';");
console.log(test); // Exception: undefined variable
```

You then need to use that custom function instead of [`$.globalEval`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) ([code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L508)) as used in [ajax for scripts](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js).

Of course this is not a catch-all method for every global variable, for something like that you would need to create a separate global object (e.g. with an `<iframe>`) to evalute the script there.

However, using JSONP might be a better idea than using variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over test.js, and must accept that test is declared as a global variable, a workaround would be to load test.js in an iframe within your page. This way test will be a global variable but only within the scope of the iframe window. From your main page, you'll be able to access it as `ifr.contentWindow.test`.

Comment: I just realized that this answer was already suggested by @Justin in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

you could try to extend an object that already exists on your page.

Say you have a script on your page like this

```
var app = {
    loadedScripts
    ,loadPageScript : function(scriptUrl, cb) {
        $.getScript(scriptUrl, cb)
            .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
                console.log(exception);
        })
    }
}

app.loadPageScript('/test.js', function(){
    app.loadedScripts['test']();
});
```

Your test.js file:

```
if(!app.loadedScripts.test){
    app.loadedScripts.test = function() {

        app.someVar = 1;

        app.someFunction = function(){
            console.log('iha');
        };
    }
}
```