# Getting Javascript files using Rawgit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github

I'm trying to include a JS file in my website via Ajax by getting it from one of my GitHub repositories, using Rawgit. For some reason, it doesn't work when I use the development or production URLs, but when I use the raw version of my files directly from Github, the problem stops. I don't experience any problems when I use the development URL for a CSS file. Does anyone know why this happens?

Here's my code:

```
$.get("https://rawgit.com/Larpee/The-Khan-Quiz/master/game.js", function (game) {
    var sketchProc = function (processingInstance) {
        with (processingInstance) {
            size(400, 400);
            frameRate(30);
            eval(game);
        }
    };

    var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
});
```

**Update:** I think the problem occurs because GitHub (not Rawgit), serves the files as `.txt` files, while RawGit serves them as `.js`.

I would still like to receive an explanation for why getting my JavaScript files with a `.js` extension isn't working, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RawGit, you get `content-type: application/javascript;charset=utf-8` as expected, and GitHub gives `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. That seems to be the only difference.

I checked your example and found that when using RawGit (and getting a script response), the `success` callback wouldn't execute at all, but using GitHub it would (adding a `console.log('foo');` statement, for example. I also found that `eval()` run on your script throws an exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createFont is not defined
```

I made a repo myself with a placeholder JS file that was syntactically correct, in which case `success` callbacks for `$.get()` on both RawGit and GitHub did execute, and later added a reference to an undefined name, which caused the call to the RawGit URL fail to execute its callback.

The lesson? When you get a script with `$.get()`, it is actually immediately executed, and if that `eval()` fails then everything ends there, silently. This is supported by [jQuery getScript load vs execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196617/jquery-getscript-load-vs-execution), which also implies that this (in my opinion) kind of crazy way of dealing with script data ended in version 2.1.0.

Which leads me to suggest that, apart from fixing your script, you should either use `$.getScript()` (not sure if you have to ensure the result header has `application/javascript`), or explicitly insert a script element with JS and have an `onload` callback:

```
(function(d, script) {
    script = d.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    script.src = '[RawGit URL]';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

Additionally, the `with` block you use should become:

```
var sketchProc = function (processing) { 
    processing.size(400, 400); 
    processing.frameRate(30); 
}

var canvas = $('#game'); // use jQuery since you have it 
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);

// game code now manipulates `processingInstance`
// either directly in scope (or even better as object with parameter)
processingInstance.draw = function () {
    var processing = this;
    // if your code originally used `processing` throughout,
    // do this so that it refers to the specific instance you've created
    // ...
}
processingInstance.loop();
// if initialized without a `.draw()` method like above, you need to start the loop manually once there is one
```

The Processing.js documentation has a lot of examples that are basically in Java and require small modifications to properly deal with JS scope. Sad!

Comment: Thank you very much for your great effort, but there's still something I don't understand: if the problem with my code is that jQuery is executing my script without even running the callback, how would avoid this behavior   (I don't want the script to be executed, just the callback, since I'm using `eval()` on the string containing the script from there)?

Comment: When `$.get()` receives data it's told is JavaScript, it calls `$.globalEval()` with that content as an argument, which runs `eval()` on the data **in the global scope**. That is the default behavior, it doesn't seem you can change it. Your problem is that when your script is executed in the global scope, it throws an error because there's (at least one) reference to a variable that's undefined in the global scope, and so the rest of `$.get()`, which includes running callbacks on the result, fails silently. There are a few different ways to fix this.

Comment: Yes, the calls to undefined functions and variables are because the code uses a library called Processing.js, which contains a lot of predefined functions for drawing and animating elements in the canvas tag. That's why I need to code to be executed only inside the callback. I guess I'll keep making the Ajax code receive the code as a text file, which solves the problem. Thank you for explaining the issue to me, it was making me go crazy. I'll give you the bounty

Comment: Why are you loading the script dynamically?

Comment: Because I needed the callback function that's executed with the Ajax call. What else would you suggest?

Comment: A quick workaround would be to set `dataType: 'text'` in the request parameters, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248491/maintain-scope-when-loading-script-with-jquery. Then you might be relatively confident that regardless of the headers with which the script is served, jQuery will think it's text and let you use it as a simple string.

Comment: A few more thoughts. You don't need the `with` keyword (it's strongly discouraged), when you call `eval()` it uses the scope of the block it's in which includes `processingInstance` and variables defined above it. But I ask why you need to load it dynamically because it seems to me that you can include the script statically in markup (underneath libraries) and then put the callback in its own script, statically after all the others. Scripts load in parallel and execute in the sequence they appear. If you want to be extra sure, use something like `$(document).ready()` around the final script.

Comment: In my mind, the use case for dynamically loading scripts seems to be: you have a lot of big scripts which do/don't need to be loaded based on user behavior. Or, you are very concerned about performance and want to load lots of scripts asynchronously (but then you need to be careful about scope). Unless one of those applies, simpler is way better. And avoiding `eval()` is always a good idea. Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: Regarding your thoughts towards using the `with` keyboard: I tried what you suggested but it didn't automatically incluede processingInstance in the scope, so it didn't work. I'm aware of the problems surrounding `with` (I know it causes problems when you want to access variables in the global scope), but I'm using it anyway because I don't access any global varibales in my script, so `with` causes no problems

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to load the script statically: I would like to do it, but I don't understand your explanation of how to do it, would you mind explaining again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138160/discussion-between-peter-behr-and-larpee).

Comment: I left you a few questions in our chat